# Injecting HttpContext-derived values into some classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt, .net-6.0

Here is the problem

A multi-layered approach. The end point/action used BLL Provider which must trim data not only using certain business criteria but also security criteria. For example, a super user can view all items and plain user can only view items assigned to his group.

The knee-jerk reaction to this - `public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(int? userId, string color, string location)`, where if user Id is not provided - get all items. But what if I want to put additional layer of protection - derive query based on a special `MyIdentityProvider`.

```cs
public class BllItemDataProvider : IBllItemDataProvider 
{
    private IMyIdentityProvider _myIdentity;
    
    public BllItemDataProvider(IMyIdentityProvider myIdentity)
    {
        _myIdentity = myIdentity;
    }

    public BllItemDataProvider(IMyIdentityProvider myIdentity)
    {
        _myIdentity = myIdentity;
    }
}
```

`MyIdentityProvider` would have `userId`, `isSuperUser`, other flags, etc.

The question is, how to wire it up so that in Web API `IHttpContextAccessor` or the `HttpContext` will hydrate `MyIdentityProvider` from the Claims I find in the `[controller].HttpContext.User.Claims`. So my controller would look like

```cs
public class ItemController : ControllerBase
{
    private IBllItemDataProvider _prov

    public ItemController (IBllItemDataProvider prov) 
    {
        _prov = prov;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]/{color}/{location?}")]
    public IActionResult SomeItems (string color, string location) 
    {
        _prov = prov.GetItems(color, location);
    }

}
```

Or, I should just create a base controller which can obtain that and inherit from it?

`public abstract class ClaimControllerBase: ControllerBase` - in constructor parse claims and setup thread principal, which can then be accessed down in the pipeline?

Thanks

**Additionally** I can add that these flags in the `MyIdentityProvider` will be taken from `HttpContext.User.Claims` which in turn come from JWT token and filled by Identity Framework. So, literally, I can take those claims and slap it in the base controller into a thread. But I don't think this a pretty solution.

Comment: Hi, I think your scenario seems to be similiar to multi-tenancy, I suggest you can check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-RO/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy).

Comment: @Rena That is actually a different subject. And we have Multi-tenancy part to (separate DB). This question however is about trimming data below multi tenancy. Once, I was part of implementation team of doing this via custom views. A user would receive roles and based on that our generator would generate data access views specifically for that user setup. It was very secure but we needed to build view removal logic because DB was getting too many. I thought this question is strictly more technical than anything else.

Comment: @Rena I got it. See solution below

Answer (score 0):

Alright, looks like this one goes into DIY, or *solve it yourself*

Added this code

```cs
// CREATED Helper
public class MyIdentityProviderHelper
{
    public static IMyIdentityProvider FetchProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
    {
        var prov = new MyIdentityProvider();
        // -- HERE parse claims and fill properties

        return prov; 
        
    }
}

// ADDED to Startup
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddTransient<IMyIdentityProvider>((s) => // factory method is the real secret here
{   
    return MyIdentityProviderHelper.FetchProvider(
               s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
});

services.AddTransient<IItemProvider, RealItemProvider>();


// DECLARED RealItemProvider
public class RealItemProvider : IItemProvider
{
    private IMyIdentityProvider _identity

    public RealItemProvider (IMyIdentityProvider identity) 
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems(string color, string location) 
    {

        IEnumerable<Item> items = null;
        if (_identity.Roles.Contains(Roles.SysAdmin))
           items = GetAllItems(color, location); // private
        else 
           items = GetUserItems(color, location); // private
    
        return items;
    }
}
```

As you see, the main soul saver here is ability to provide a factory for the object and use factory of another object to pass the retrieved object